# auto scale k8s pod based on moment in a day

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to achieve the following, suppose I've enough resource (CPU/node pool):
During UTC 00:00 to UTC 3:00, pod replicas=10
During UTC 3:01 to UTC 23:59, pod replicas=3.

And if possible, change node pool size accordingly as well. I checked documentation, and looks like I only have CPU utilization trigger, yet the CPU usage of my running pod is quite low, 1% roughly, and there is no 'full workload' concept.

Answer (score -1):

Inside GCP you can use [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) and run your own [VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/), or use a [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) to create a [cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture). Depending on which you use, you can autoscale them:

> [Scaling Based on Stackdriver Monitoring Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics)

You can use these GCP docs on how to install [stackdriver agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) manually and choose the desired [metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent) for memory monitoring. Keep in mind that stackdriver is available for [premium tier accounts](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing_v2)

> Autoscale for cluster inside Kubernetes Engine

Inside Kubernetes Engine you can choose the [cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).

> Note that cluster autoscaler works based on **Pod resource requests**, that is, how many resources your Pods have *requested*. Cluster autoscaler does not take into account the resources your Pods are actively *using*. Essentially, cluster autoscaler trusts that the Pod resource requests you've provided are accurate and schedules Pods on nodes based on that assumption.

Comment: thanks for providing the reply. However, this does not answer my question. I've already know in the official docs they mentioned "cluster autoscaler works based on Pod resource requests", and what I want is based on time not resource.

Comment: You can use `crontab` to schedule new pods. So at 25:59 you would launch 7 new pods and at 3:00 stop them, or set their liveness.